# IntelliJ no longer remembers open tabs

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

IntelliJ no longer remembers open tabs --- when I close IntelliJ, then reopen it, all my tabs are closed.  None remain open.  I'm not sure if a recent update was applied that caused it or if a setting got changed.

Anyone experience this or know how to correct?

Comment: So far it could be either access permissions (broken or invalid; e.g. unable to save opened tabs into config file when closing the project) .. or hight latency when accessing source files (e.g. working over network ... or some antivirus slowing down access to files) .. so IDE thinks that file is no longer present and closes the tab. 1) Check `idea.log` for possible hints (`Help | Show Log in...`) 2) Does it happen with other projects? What about brand new project? 3) Will it do any better if you do `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE (should not, but just in case)?

Comment: Thanks... Let me investigate further based on your questions/recommendations.  I've not yet noticed a pattern, but some projects open with all tabs closed, some projects still have the tabs active.  Stay tuned...

Comment: I checked idea.log and really didnt see anything that stood out.  I performed the Invalidate Caches, with no change.

Answer (score 0):

Open tabs state is saved in `.idea/workspace.xml` file inside the project directory. Make sure this file is not removed or changed externally (like reverted from the version control).

Check the [local history](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-local-history.html) of this file.

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be the culprit...  I found the file workspace.xml as you mentioned.  The files do exist and really shouldnt be getting changed externally - the entire .idea folder is excluded in my projects.

I noticed this morning... when the project opens initially, my previous tabs are open - I saw them.  Once IntelliJ finished booting up completely, all the tabs closed. @LazyOne

Comment: Any third-party plug-ins installed? Do you have distraction free or presentation modes enabled?